# How to heat water to 80°C?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, temperature, water

I'm trying to figure out an easy water to get 80°c to consistently make the perfect cup of coffee. Let's assume room temperature water is 22°c.

What is the ratio of boiling water to room temp water to achieve 80°? What is the formula with room temp being variable?

Comment: If you explain the down-vote it might help minimize future offenses.

Comment: I suspect it is a "lack of effort" downvote. What do you know about mixing liquids of different temperatures? How much heat can you extract from 1 gram of water when you cool it from 100C to 80C - and how much water does that let you heat from 22 to 80?

Comment: X grams gives 20 calories/gram to y grams that need 58 cal/gram (one calorie heats one gram by one degree C). What is $x/y$.

Comment: To consistently make the perfect cup of coffee at exactly 80°c, you cannot assume that by some magic the room temperature water is always going to be 22°c.

Comment: Have a look at [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583). Regardless of whether or not this is *actual* homework, it is homework-like since this is about calculating some specific value/just finding a specific formula.

Comment: @ACuriousMind - ah, I see. I thought I was keeping more accurate by removing the homework tag. Sorry.

Comment: Use a thermometer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post seems an awful lot like a homework question, so you should probably tag it as a homework-like question.

If by "cup" you mean 250 mL on the dot, then we can say that the ratio of boiling water (100 Celsius) to room temperature water (22 Celsius) to achieve 80 degrees is

$$ \frac {(T_1)(V_1) + (T_2)(V_2)}{V_1 + V_2}$$
In your case, we have: 
$$ 80^oC = \frac {(100^oC)(x mL) + (22^oC)(250 - x mL)}{250 mL}$$
And you can solve for x to find the amount of boiling water you need to add to a certain initial amount of room temperature water.

That should be enough to get you started, we can't give away the full answer for the sake of academic integrity.

Comment: The ratio is independent of the volume

Comment: I swear on my stackexchange secret decoder ring this is not a homework question.

Comment: If it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck......

Comment: I do agree that this is **indeed** homework question and I am saying this from experience, because I already know what are homework questions are. When I was pupil in high school, I had a lot of homework to do in physics. Your question appears to be one of these physics questions that I had to answer in high school.

Comment: Just came to say that I came here looking for an answer to this question--not as a homework question. I have similar motivation--I want to make matcha at my parents' _today_, I needed a way to get the water to 80'C. I guess this just says that if such a question is used in HW assignments, it's an actually helpful / applicable question. I don't have memory of applicable questions in high school growing up. 

PS. Thanks for the answer :)